# Using jQuery functions in/as higher order functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, higher-order-functions

I was trying to use `$.fn.show` (and other jQuery functions) within higher-order functions.

What I originally wanted to have was a function that *applies a given function to all elements returned by a collection of other functions applied to a given element*. Something that would look like this:

```
function mapOn( func, genratingFunc, element ){
    $(generatingFuncs).each(function(){
        var buf = $(element);
        while(buf.length){ // run as long as elements are returned
            func(buf);
            buf = this(buf);
        }
    });
}
```

I needed such a function to apply some functions to a couple of DOM nodes and their parents and/or children in a handy, expressive way. Let's say we want to hide the node with the ID *hideMyFamily* and its children. I don't know any handy way to do this with jQuery so I'd run hide() on `$("#hideMyFamily").children()` and on `$("#hideMyFamily").children().children()` and so on until the *length* of the collection was 0 (and on `$("#hideMyFamily")` itself of course).
Thing is, running `mapOn( $.fn.show, [$.fn.children], $("#hideMyFamily") )` won't do the job since you apparently cannot just apply `$.fn.show` to an element/collection.

So what I came up with is this:

For each of the jQuery's functions that I need to specify another function (within global scope) that looks like this:

```
function _show(e){ $(e).show(); }
```

For each of the jQuery's "generating" functions I specify another "work-around function":

```
function _id(e){ return $(e); }
function _children(e){ return $(e).children(); }
```

And then I can specify my "multiMap" function which looks like this:

```
function multiMap(func, generators, elem){
    $(generators).each(function(){
        var buf = $(elem);
        var buf2 = [];
        while (buf.length && buf[0] !== buf2[0]) {
            func(buf);
            buf2 = buf;
            buf = this(buf);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I can run my handy function `multiMap(_show, [_id, _children], "hideMyFamily")` to hide the element itself and all of its children.

Now, to get to the point, my question is: Is there any more elegant way to achieve the desired behaviour? Is there any jQuery magic I didn't take into account?

tl;dr Is there a handy way to use jQuery's functions like show() and hide() on nodes/collections in a way like `$.fn.show( $("someElements") )`?

Comment: wouldn't using `hide()` on a parent element, also hide all of it's children as well?...without having to call `hide()` for each child?

Comment: What's your question? I needed to hide all items of a subtree by default and then display some of the nodes again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
You can do `$.fn.show.call($("some-elements"))`.

I haven't fully gone through your more elaborate example, but that seems to be what you're looking for. And for your final example, you could write things as:

```
multiMap($.fn.show, [_id, _children], "hideMyFamily")
```

and then in mutliMap do `f.call` or something like that and I believe that would work.